# How do you handle bower components properly when it comes to references, concat, and minify?

Tags: javascript, npm, bower, azure-devops-extensions

I recently started an endeavor on creating a VSTS Extension. I utilized bower to automatically pull in the latest `vss-web-extension-sdk` component, and everything works fine so far. One thing that bothers me is that I had to reference the script in the following way:

`<script src="bower_components/vss-web-extension-sdk/lib/VSS.SDK.min.js"></script>`

---

I understand that I can change the bower components directory, but should it be a unique name or can it be `scripts`, which is the folder where my own scripts reside?

Additionally:

- Should I (and how do I) concatenate components together when it comes to production?
- Should I minify all of my components (Javascript) together, even though I'm already provided `*.min.js` files?

I've come across other similar questions relating to this, but I'm not utilizing `Grunt` or `Gulp`, just `npm` and `bower`. I ask this because I want to ensure that my production code does not identify which tooling I used (`npm`, `bower`), and I want the production code to be as proper as possible, which may require me to minify all JS together (I'm not sure on this one)?